# Unable to read a Sqlite DB from Assets folder Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I can't read a Sqlite database from the Android Assets folder, if I do a debug it always throws an IOException, here is my code:

Another question, should I use "/data/data/com.example.bat0/databases/" or "/databases/"? the database is located in the assets/databases folder

```
public class SqlLiteDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "db_toulouse_barcelona.sqlite";
    private static final String DB_PATH =  "/data/data/com.example.bat0/databases/";
    //private static final String DB_PATH =  "/databases/";
    private Context context;

    public SqlLiteDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);

        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            try {
                android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase checkDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH+DB_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                if(checkDB != null){

                    checkDB.close();

                }
                copyDatabase(dbFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
            }
        }

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    private void copyDatabase(File dbFile) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer);
        }

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: If you tried them both, then what is the problem?

Comment: Check out this tutorial, it should point you in the right direction.
https://riptutorial.com/android/example/16609/create-database-from-assets-folder